# Joomla Error: Table 'sitename.#__template_styles' doesn't exist: Table 'sitename.#__extensions' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, joomla, localhost

Today I was trying to copy a website in Joomla on my locahost, after the website download via FTP, I the folder in mt XAMPP/htdocs xampps's folder.
I downloaded the DB and I followed the Joomla Guide to set the configuration.php but after checking more and more times that everything was correct I keep getting this error message.

```
 Error: Table 'websitename.#__template_styles' doesn't exist: Table 'websitename.#__extensions' doesn't exist
```

I have been looking for this problem anyway but none of the solutions I found work.

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, I recommend extending your Stack Exchange citizenship to [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  After registering your account in the dedicated community, if you would like to migrate your question there, just ping me and I'll help with that process.

Comment: Thanks Mick, if you could help me I would be very happy

Comment: I would like to put this question in front of Joomla-knowledgeable  volunteers at JSE.  Please create an account there and then I will flag this page to be migrated there.